# Search an item in google using robotframework

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am not able to understand how I can set my robotframework's script to do a simple search on google.

This is my script:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation                                      This is a basic test
Library                                            Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${url}                                              https://www.google.com
${browser}                                          chrome
${text}                                             xpath=//*[@id="lst-ib"]

*** Test Cases ***
User can open page
[Documentation]                                 As a user I can open the 
google page

open browser                                    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
wait until page contains                        ${url}
close browser

User fill in the Search text box
[Documentation]                                 The user search 'Test 
Definition'

open browser                                    ${URL}  ${browser}
wait until page contains                        ${URL}
input text                                      ${text}  Test Definition
click button                                    btnK
wait until page contains                        Test
```

Can you help me where I made the mistake?

Comment: what happens when you run this test, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: I have this error:   WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk"> is not clickable at point (516, 411). Other element would receive the click: <div class="sbqs_c">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)

Comment: The error is telling you useful information -- that something is on top of the input box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the lack of spacing before the keywords was unintentional. To me only the submit button did not use the right path. So, this is something I changed and added the `close browser`. The below example works for me.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation                                      This is a basic test
Library                                            Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${url}                                              https://www.google.com
${browser}                                          chrome
${text}                                             xpath=//*[@id="lst-ib"]
${search_button}                                    css=input.lsb

*** Test Cases ***
User can open page
    [Documentation]                                 As a user I can open the google page
    open browser                                    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    wait until page contains                        ${url}
    close browser

User fill in the Search text box
    [Documentation]                                 The user search 'Test Definition'
    open browser                                    ${URL}    ${browser}
    wait until page contains                        ${URL}
    input text                                      ${text}  Test Definition
    click element                                    ${search_button} 
    wait until page contains                        Test
    sleep     5s
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 0):

May be late to the party but I don't think your xpath is correct. Type css like below

```
*** Variables ***
| ${GoogleBaseUrl} | https://www.google.com/
| ${GoogleForm} | css=form[name=f]
| ${GoogleQuery} | css=input[name=q]

*** KeyWords ***
Open Google Search
    open browser  ${GoogleBaseUrl}    firefox  gl
    wait until element is visible  ${GoogleForm}
    wait until element is visible  ${GoogleQuery}
```

Then you just need to be sure you always go back to the main page...

```
Do Google Search
    [Arguments]  ${term}
    log to console  Do Google Search with "${term}"
    switch browser  gl
    go to  ${GoogleBaseUrl}
    wait until element is visible  ${GoogleForm}
    wait until element is visible  ${GoogleQuery}
    input text  ${GoogleQuery}  ${EMPTY}
    input text  ${GoogleQuery}   ${term}
    submit form
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be just to add a query parameter to the url.

```
*** Settings ***

Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

| ${GoogleForm} | css=form[name=f]
| ${GoogleQuery} | css=input[name=q]
| ${term}   | robotframework
| ${GoogleBaseUrl} | https://www.google.com/search?q=${term}
*** Test Cases ***
This is sample test case
    [documentation]  Google test
    [tags]  regression
    Open Browser  ${GoogleBaseUrl}          chrome  ch

    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
```